# What request info to log in an ASP.Net MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, analytics

I'm not concerned with logging for defect fixing, but more for google-like analytics.  Does anyone have a killer schema that they use to make analytics easier.  I'd prefer to have control over the analytics on my site and am looking for good practices/ideas/implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first look at the properties available in the current `HttpRequest` class such as:

- HttpMethod
- Path
- PathInfo
- QueryString
- RawUrl
- UrlReferrer
- UserAgent

You may also want to record, if applicable:

`HttpSessionState.SessionID`

You could then log the information you need into a database for every request for later analysis. How you analyse the data depends on what you want to know.